# why we cannot use "=" to shared_ptr or unique_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++11, initialization, shared-ptr, unique-ptr

I fount the syntax got compile error.

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p = new int(5);

31 41 E:\temprory (delete it if u like)\1208.cpp [Error] conversion from 'int*' to non-scalar type 'std::shared_ptr<int>' requested
```

But it is O.K

```
std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int(5));
```

The same as `unique_ptr`;

But I don't know why it is prohibited.

Comment: The constructor is marked `explicit`, and therefore you can't copy initialize

Answer (score 12):

The constructor of [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr) and [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr) taking raw pointer are `explicit`; `std::shared_ptr<int> p = new int(5);` is [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization#Notes), which doesn't consider `explicit` constructors.

> Copy-initialization is less permissive than direct-initialization: explicit constructors are not converting constructors and are not considered for copy-initialization.

For [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), `explicit` constructors are considered then `std::shared_ptr<int> p(new int(5));` works fine.

#### Why the constructor is `explicit`?

To prevent unintentional implicit conversion and ownership transfer. e.g.

```
void foo(std::unique_ptr<int> p) { ... }
```

then

```
int* pi = new int(5);
foo(pi); // if implicit conversion is allowed, the ownership will be transfered to the parameter p
// then when get out of foo pi is destroyed, and can't be used again
```

Comment: I believe OP was asking about the rationale of decision to make this constructor explicit.

Answer (score 5):

C++ doesn't allow copy-initialisation of a  `shared_ptr` from a raw pointer because `shared_ptr` would be too easy to end up with an accidental implicit conversion from some arbitrary raw pointer into a `shared_ptr` that doesn't actually manage it.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine if you accidentally passed an `int *` pointer that you had to a function that took a `std::shared_ptr<int>`. When the function completed, the pointer would be freed. If you really want to transfer ownership, you should indicate so explicitly.